# Will old-style chrome new tab page come back?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Maybe from chrome 32, the new tab page was changed...

The thumb is too small, and the recently-closed-tabs is disappeared, etc..

These changes make big trouble to me.

At first I can enable instant-extended-api flag to set back, but now it doesn't work.

I've been searching for solutions, but there are all bad news, e.g.(a response from chrome forum)
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/THPuNSLtljg%5B1-25-false%5D?

Someone said there are some extensions solving this problem, but I can't find it.

Is this an impossible problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like there is no ideal solution to this problem. The most pertinent information I was able to find is under that same thread you posted, it looks like the [official Google response](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/chrome/chrome/THPuNSLtljg)
They do provide suggested extensions on that page, although none of them were to my liking, I ended up sticking to their new New Tab page for now, but the Logo and Search box are extremely annoying.

[Replace New Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/replace-new-tab-page/cnkhddihkmmiiclaipbaaelfojkmlkja)

[Awesome New Tab Page 2](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-new-tab-page-2/abdholagkagimalmpmohnkmpcbjomlgp/related)

[Modern New Tab Page (Includes recently closed tabs option)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modern-new-tab-page/ogllliimbhgmclkgjldeffhjbhaenapo/related)

[SPOTS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/spots-a-better-way-to-sta/ejocekekgcaldnmjngfdbmbeebcekelc)

Another possible work around is to install an older version of Chrome which does not have auto-update (Chromium 32.0.1690.0), haven't tried it myself though.
[This](https://superuser.com/questions/720246/how-to-remove-google-search-and-smaller-tile-in-chrome-33s-new-tab-page) super user thread is also pertinent

Comment: thanks for your answer. old-version-chrome is unacceptable.. i'll try these extensions you suggested

Comment: There is a solution to remove google logo and search box ------- switch to another default search engine...

Comment: I prefer Google search... it's just since it's already available through the omnibar I don't need the logo and an extra search bar taking up half the screen... I've half the mind to write a script that will automatically remove those parts from the html :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try "New Tab Reloaded" on the webstore, which recreates the old new tab page as an extension. Also there is a "New Tab Reloaded (Extended)" that has the apps page. The extended one supports almost all previous new tab page features such as recently closed pages, creating app shortcuts, etc in Chrome Dev or Canary.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use
*Awesome New Tab Page*.

There are warnings about adds in the new version, but it is possible to switch adds off after the install from the tools-extensions menu.  Yes, the *permissions* are needed, they claim it is induced by google. For the moment my situation is better than before.
(i can't comment, so i post)